# Is it a good programming practice to use a ++ operator which actually does a post increment?

Tags: java, coding-style

In many cases, mostly when you are looping through an array and assigning values to the elements, there is a scope to use post increment operator. Is it considered a good practice.

For example, in the following code where the copying is being done which one is better.

```
int [] to_assign;
int [] to_include;
int [] from_assign;

// Version 1
int count = 0;
while(i<<some_value>){
  if(to_include[i]==1)
     to_assign[count++] = from_assign[i];
}

// Version 2
int count = 0;
while(i<<some_value>){
  if(to_include[i]==1)
  {     
      to_assign[count] = from_assign[i];
      count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: using ++ is given as a handy for the users instead of writing the entire syntax and 2 things are provided one is pre increment - which increments and then is used in the operation and the other is post increment - first used in the operation and later incremented

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - anyone who writes code like that **deserves** to have problems ...

Comment: @StephenC Yes I was wrong Its Java!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - they deserve problems *irrespective* of the language!!

Comment: Voted to close because the OP's edits to the original question rendered half of the Answers meaningless.

Comment: @StephenC I mean undefined about behaviour of ++ in c but not in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's purely a matter of style. Personally, I'd use whichever one makes the most logical sense. If the increment is logically part of the operation, then use the post-increment. If not, use a separate increment operation.

Also, when you use an increment operator alone, it is generally preferred to use a pre-increment. While it won't matter with simple types like integers, with more complex types, it can be much more efficient in languages like C++ that have operator overloading because a pre-increment doesn't need two instances to be around at the same time. There's no performance impact with Java, because it doesn't have operator overloading, but if you want a consistent style rule, it should be pre-increment rather than post-increment.

Comment: In Java, it makes no difference from a performance perspective ...

Comment: @StephenC I tried to make that more explicit.

Comment: Well yea ... but this is a Java question, so even *mentioning* the performance implications of `++` in C++ is superfluous (IMO).

Comment: @StephenC: It's the reason the convention is to use pre-increment rather than post-increment.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such convention in Java.  It might be a habit of C++ programmers who have switched to Java ... but I've never seen a style guide that favours one form over the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that the second solution is perhaps slightly cleaner to read.  I.e. the eye observes  that an assignment is being made, and then that there is an increment.  Having them both together on the same line makes it slightly less easy to read at a glance.  So, I'd prefer solution two.

That said, this is a matter of preference. I don't think one can speak of an established best or better practice here.

In the days when every last ounce of performance mattered, the first version would have been preferred, because the compiler has a higher change of emitting slightly more optimal assembly in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any good compiler will optimize this for you anyway. All are good as long as they are human-readable.

"++" is a leftover from the days of pointer arithmetic -- there are some of us who prefer "+= 1" for integers. But the compiler should manage simple cases like this correctly, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Modern compilers optimize this kind of code anyway, so in the end it doesn't matter how and where you're incrementing the variable.

From a style perspective, the first version is smaller, and for some easier to read.

From a code comprehension point of view, the second version is easier to understand for beginner developers.

From a performance point of view, ignoring compiler optimizations, this is even faster:

```
// Version 3
int count = -1;
while(i<<some_value>){
    if(to_include[i]==1)
    {
        to_assign[++count] = from_assign[i];
    }
}
```

It's faster because in theory `count++` creates a temporary copy of the value before the increment, while `++count` increments and uses the same variable. But again, this kind of *premature optimization* is not needed any more, since compilers can detect such frequent cases and optimizes the generated code.

Comment: Semantically, no, and neither are V1 and V2. But the final outcome is almost the same, except that at the end the final value of `count` will be different.